# Crystal Report-Running Total

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a problem with running Total in Crsystal report9
if their is no values available for a Paticular field how can we return the running total as '0'

Answer (score 3):

Instead of display the Running Total directly in your report create a Formula Field based on the Running Total and drag it into the report.

Your formula should look like this (Crystal Syntax)...

```
if ISNULL({#RunningTotalField}) then
    "0.00"
else
    ToText(RunningTotalField, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no data for that particular group, then Crystal won't show it easily. Your options are :

1) Use subreports to display the values for a particular group, and keep the main report just looking at the table(s) containing the group headers.

2) Use a stored procedure as the source so you have full control over the SQL that is run.

The problem is that as soon as you use a field to group, Crystal will only return records where that field has been used. If it was simply in the Details section you could modify the link to a LEFT JOIN and it wouldn't matter, but the group forces the INNER JOIN which means the groups without data are not returned.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Running Totals don't show up if there are no records that match your criteria.  An alternative is to use a set of formulas calculated in various sections of the report.  The technique is widely described in the Crystal literature.  For example, [this TekTips](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=182) gives a very succinct overview of your options.

You set up an initialising formula in each header, with the evaluation time directive "WhilePrintingRecords". This approach was the only one available for doing running totals in the "good ol' days" before RunningTotal objects were available.